# I can't set up a samba share

Tags: server, permissions, samba

I've been trying to set up a samba share on my local network for 3 days now and I keep running in to the same problem. I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure it out.

When I try to access it through my Windows 10 machine I get the following message:

```
\\192.168.1.10 is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource.
Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. 
Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, 
using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.
```

My Windows Credential Manager is empty.

I use the default [global] config and added the following to the bottom of the smb.conf file:

```
[media]
path = /mnt/media
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 666
directory mask = 777
force user = sjonnie
force group = sjonnie
```

I created the user "sjonnie" and user 'smbpasswd -a sjonnie' to set a password.

File permissions (also tried nobody:nogroup):

```
drwxrwxrwx   4 sjonnie sjonnie       4096 May  8 17:59 mnt
```

Contents of mnt:

```
drwxrwxrwx 4 sjonnie sjonnie 4096 May  8 18:33 data
drwxrwxrwx 3 sjonnie sjonnie 4096 May  8 16:10 media
```

If you need any more information, ask and I will provide.

Comment: Which version of samba?  if it is less than 4 then it's possible that you need to enable smb1 protocol in windows 10.   Control panel->programs and features->turn windows features on/off.   enable SMB 1 protocol and see if that helps.

Comment: `directory mask = 777` I hope samba does not allow this. Please use 770 (and 660 for files) There is no reason to open your system up to "others". Please also have a look in  `/var/log/` and if any file is updated when you try to connect. It might give a clue to what is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @Morbius1 for your help.

After few more hours of trying things I found the answer.

It turns out the problem wasn't with the Linux machine and therefore not with the Samba share.

My Windows 10 machine kept the shares I had previous in the background. I couldn't see them in the explorer but when I ran `net use` in the CMD I found there were 2 still linked (from previous mounting attempts). I then used `net use * /delete` to remove those.

Hope this helps someone else so he and or she doesn't waste 3 days pulling their hair out.
If you have any questions, send me a message.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this happen when the server only has one share especially one that allows guest access. Did you have a different share that required credentials at one point?

Anyway, The Linux samba server can be addressed 2 different ways: By ip address and my name ( mDNS or NetBIOS ). Windows regards these as two different hosts even though they are the same machine.

What I would do is address the Linux samba server by it's mDNS host name: `\\hostname.local\media`

Note:

[1] Run `hostname` on the Linux server to find the hostname of the machine then when you address it in Win10 add a `.local` at the end.

[2] Win10 can do mDNS by default. Ubuntu desktop can as well but if you are using Ubuntu Server you need to install a package:

```
sudo apt install avahi-daemon
```

[3] If you intend on keeping this as a guest accessible share I suggest removing sjonnie from the samba password database ( smbpasswd -x sjonnie ). I think this is contributing to the problem.